# How to select window by name, which is contained in a variable?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Could you advise how can I select window by name, which is contained in variable?

Name of window generates ramdom and this value exists in my ${addressId} variable.

I tried to use:

```
Select Window    ${addressId}
```

but it doesn't work. I have got `NoSuchWindowException`. Any ideas how to switch windows?

Comment: how is the name genereated? Are you certain that this generated name is something that the `select window` will accept (title, name, url, etc)?

Comment: yep. it is a string with id, which is a title of window

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it is correct. The logical explanation is that `${addressId}` doesn't match any window titles. You can use [Get window titles](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Window%20Titles) in your test to see what robot thinks the window titles are, and then you can log `${addressId}` to see if it matches any of them.